# My Inner class main function is not executing even when I tried java outter$inner

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm facing difficulty in executing a main method in an inner class. The outer class main method is executing fine, and even other class main methods are executing fine. However, when I'm trying to execute java Outer$Inner it executes the main method of Outer class rather than Inner class.

Here is the code:

```java
class outer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Outer class");
    }
    class inner{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Inner class");   
        }
    }
}
class c{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Another class");
    }
}
```

```
Output:
PS C:\Users\MY_PROJECTS> java outer
Outer class
PS C:\Users\MY_PROJECTS> java outer$inner
Outer class
PS C:\Users\MY_PROJECTS> java c
Another class
```

All class files are generated in same directory.
Also what irritating me here is this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3hMe.png)
there is no option to run or debug main method in inner class.

So I'm trying to find why this is happening.

Comment: I have an error :  .\example.java:6: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Outer.Inner. You should really copy the text of your program instead of a screen copy. I had to type it again. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481680/error-illegal-static-declaration-in-inner-class

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Your code compiles and runs fine (producing _"Inner class"_ with Java 17).

Comment: The second part of your question is related to the specific editor you're using. Please focus on only one question/problem per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a `Illegal static declaration in inner class Outer.Inner` error with your program.

I had to change it to:

```java
class Outer{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("OUTER");
  }
  static class Inner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("INNER");
    }
  }
}
```

See the `static` class.

Then, I can run the INNER class:

```
PS D:\> java 'Outer$Inner'
INNER
```

Note the quotes. If you omit them, Powershell will run `java Outer` (`$Inner` is replaced by nothing since the variable is not defined).

Common usages write class names with a capital like this example.

Comment: Recent versions of Java allow static methods in inner classes (non-static nested classes). For example, the code posted in the question works fine in Java 17.

Comment: The actual problem is solved by your solution at the end about PowerShell treating $ specially, so the OP should use `java 'inner$outer'`