# Illegal static declaration in inner class in jsp scriplet

Tags: java, html, google-maps, jsp, latitude-longitude

What does this error mean?? how to resolve it?My error is at main statement please suggest me solution or anyother approach better than this for getting latitude and longitude values with place as input....Thank you.

```
 <html>
    <%@page import="javaroots.latlong.*" %>
     <%@page import="javaroots.latlong.Location" %>
     <%@page import="javaroots.latlong.Geometry" %>
     <%@page import="javaroots.latlong.Result" %>
     <%@page import="javaroots.latlong.GoogleResponse" %>

     <%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream" %>
     <%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;" %>
     <%@page import=" java.io.IOException" %>
     <%@page import="java.io.InputStream" %>
     <%@page import="java.net.URL" %>
     <%@page import="java.net.URLConnection" %>
      <%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
     <%@page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" %>
  <%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" %>




<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <%! 
        public static class AddressConverter  {
 private static final String URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

 public GoogleResponse convertToLatLong(String fullAddress) throws IOException {

  URL url = new URL(URL + "?address="
+ URLEncoder.encode(fullAddress, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");
  // Open the Connection
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream() ;
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  GoogleResponse response = (GoogleResponse)mapper.readValue(in,GoogleResponse.class);
  in.close();
  return response;


 }

 public GoogleResponse convertFromLatLong(String latlongString) throws IOException {

  URL url = new URL(URL + "?latlng="
+ URLEncoder.encode(latlongString, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");
  // Open the Connection
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream() ;
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  GoogleResponse response = (GoogleResponse)mapper.readValue(in,GoogleResponse.class);
  in.close();
  return response;

 } 

 public class GoogleResponse {
    private Result[] results ;
 private String status ;

 public Result[] getResults() {
  return results;
 }
 public void setResults(Result[] results) {
  this.results = results;
 }
 public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }
 public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
 }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 

  {



  GoogleResponse res = new AddressConverter().convertToLatLong("uppal, India");
  if(res.getStatus().equals("OK"))
  {
   for(Result result : res.getResults())
   {
    System.out.println("Lattitude of address is :"  +result.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
    System.out.println("Longitude of address is :" + result.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
    System.out.println("Location is " + result.getFormatted_address());
   }
  }
  else
   {
   System.out.println(res.getStatus());
  }

  System.out.println("\n");







}
  }    



    public class Geometry {

 private Location location ;

 private String location_type;

 @JsonIgnore
 private Object bounds;

 @JsonIgnore

 private Object viewport;

 public Location getLocation() {
  return location;
 }

 public void setLocation(Location location) {
  this.location = location;
 }

 public String getLocation_type() {
  return location_type;
 }

 public void setLocation_type(String location_type) {
  this.location_type = location_type;
 }

 public Object getBounds() {
  return bounds;
 }

 public void setBounds(Object bounds) {
  this.bounds = bounds;
 }

 public Object getViewport() {
  return viewport;
 }

 public void setViewport(Object viewport) {
  this.viewport = viewport;
 }




}
public class Location {

 private String lat;

 private String lng;

 public String getLat() {
  return lat;
 }

 public void setLat(String lat) {
  this.lat = lat;
 }

 public String getLng() {
  return lng;
 }

 public void setLng(String lng) {
  this.lng = lng;
}
}
public class Result {

 private String formatted_address;

 private boolean partial_match;

 private Geometry geometry;



@JsonIgnore
private String place_id;
 @JsonIgnore
 private Object address_components;

 @JsonIgnore
 private Object types;

 public String getFormatted_address() {
  return formatted_address;
 }

 public void setFormatted_address(String formatted_address) {
  this.formatted_address = formatted_address;
 }

 public boolean isPartial_match() {
  return partial_match;
 }

 public void setPartial_match(boolean partial_match) {
  this.partial_match = partial_match;
 }

 public Geometry getGeometry() {
  return geometry;
 }

 public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
  this.geometry = geometry;
 }

 public Object getAddress_components() {
  return address_components;
 }

 public void setAddress_components(Object address_components) {
  this.address_components = address_components;
 }

 public Object getTypes() {
  return types;
 }

 public void setTypes(Object types) {
  this.types = types;
 }



}


        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove static from `public static class AddressConverter`

Comment: no improvement showing same error  :(  @ E.Doroskevic

Comment: Could you provide stacktrace? So, we can identify what is happening wrong?

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly. It helps to reveal problems.

Comment: Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\generated\classes
C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\newjsp1_jsp.java:378: reached end of file while parsing
}
1 error
C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:941: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:284: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declarations. you can not define static method in inner class. You can not Use :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

In your inner class.

For more details see:
[Modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440010/modifier-static-is-only-allowed-in-constant-variable-declarations).

Comment: @sangusainathvarma For more understanding read jsp specification for jsp scriptlet  and also jsp specification.