# error: Illegal static declaration in inner class asignacion1.sumar

Tags: java, methods, overloading

the practice is about Method overloading

the problem is in this lines:

```
public class asignacion1 {


public asignacion1() {
}

class sumar {

    public static int calcular (int num1, int num2){
        int r = num1 + num2;
        return r;
    }

    public static double calcular (double n1, double n2){
        double r = n1 + n2;
        return r;
    }


}
```

Comment: You'd have to show more code. These lines don't have a problem

Comment: You have these static methods inside an inner class which is not allowed. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440068/1435985) for an explanation.

Comment: "Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are compile-time constant fields"

Comment: can you explain me that? please

Comment: sumar is an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). As the error says inner classes cannot have static members unless they are compile-time constant fields. The two versions of the `calcular(...)` methods are currently static members since they are using the static modifier in the method declaration and this is not allowed for inner classes. Either remove static from the method declarations or do not make `sumar` an inner class.