# Error of simple calculating process

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate: `x(t) = 0.5at^2 + vit + xi`

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {


public static void main(String[] args){

double  gravity =-9.81; // Earth's gravity in m/s^2

double  initialVelocity = 0.0; // starting velocity of the object

double  fallingTime = 10.0; // time in seconds that the object falls

double  initialPosition = 1000.0; // Starting position in meters, the calculation will      determine the ending position in meters

double  finalPosition = 0.0;

System.out.println("The object's position after " + fallingTime +" seconds is           "+finalPosition + " m.");

}
}
```

I have an error and cannot find a solution for the bellow error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class javaapplication1.JavaApplication1, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have tried to add: `static`   to `public class GravityCalculator`

as explained under this question :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440010/modifier-static-is-only-allowed-in-constant-variable-declarations
```

But I still having the same error. Is it because of run.xml file that can't be located or there is a sytax error I have in my code?

Please help me out here, this my first code in java.

Comment: You need to delete`public static class GravityCalculator {` because you create class in the class

Comment: Hi Vasyl, I have edited my question by removing public static class GravityCalculator { and now I have a new error : Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication2.JavaApplication2
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: @NimitPatel I have opened a new java class, got new error : Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication2.JavaApplication2
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Looks like more of an IDE setup issue than a java issue.